# Synfig studio: how does one make generic animated skeletons

Tags: 3d, animation, modeling, synfig-studio

I have cutout characters which their bodies are made of limbs in separate images. Say, I have a generic humanoid skeleton, and I have animations which make this skeleton move, and I want any new model I have to able able to be swapped in the place of the skeleton so every model can be animated from the same animations without having to animate every single model every time. Or if you could point me to the right documentation to achieve that, I don't know where to start.

Comment: I'm sure I saw a duplicate question here somewhere... but TL/DR you can't with 2D software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, this isn't possible in Synfig (but I don't know the program).

It is possible with Adobe Character Animator 
intro tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUtRnMMOTmo

I presume it's also possible with the DUIK plugin for After Effects.